# How to Upgrade Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10 final not Beta without a cd

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, 12.10, 13.10, upgrade

I tried doing this before from the software updater and it upgraded me to 12.10 and then I upgraded to 13.04 and then when I tried to upgrade to 13.10 it said that it can't because I'm using a daily build so how do I avoid upgrading to a daily build from Ubuntu 12.04 as I assume that the 12.10 was a daily build install too. Also if I try to upgrade via cd/dvd it hangs when it asks me if I want to install updates and or proprietary software.

Answer (score 0):

you can upgrade to 12.10 by changing a setting in the update-manager.

To do this: 
open update-manager
click 'settings'
under updates tab change 'For long-term support versions' to 'For any new version'

[This article goes into more depth and has pictures](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-12.04-lts-precise-pangolin-to-12.10-quantal-quetzal-desktop-and-server)

Comment: I know that but it's upgrading me to 12.10 beta,  not the final release

Comment: aren't all releases considered beta besides the lts release?

Comment: No, look at: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/08/ubuntu-14-04-lts-release-schedule. As you can see their is a Beta and a final for plain Ubuntu